# Does Ghidra have an equivalent to IDA's "Evaluate Expression" feature?

Tags: ida, ghidra

This is the window that appears when you press `Shift` + `/`.

Example:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure if there is something inbuilt, but you can write a simple Python script and assign a key binding to that script
as below:

```
#TODO evaluates a string expression as Numeral and formats it in multiple radix
#@author  blabb
#@category _NEW_
#@keybinding Shift-SLASH

import ghidra
exp = askString("Expression","Expression")
print("Expression is %s" % exp)
val = eval(exp)
print(ghidra.util.NumericUtilities.formatNumber(val,2))
print(ghidra.util.NumericUtilities.formatNumber(val,8))
print(ghidra.util.NumericUtilities.formatNumber(val,10))
print(ghidra.util.NumericUtilities.formatNumber(val,16))
```

Executed and screenshotted as below:

[image]

Comment: I think is now available also as a built-in feature, look [there](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/NationalSecurityAgency/ghidra/blob/Ghidra_10.1_build/Ghidra/Configurations/Public_Release/src/global/docs/WhatsNew.html) for Pure Emulation

Comment: @zi0Black Pure Emulation  does   string parsing  splitting  and evaluating  ? i dont think so it might be related to Emulating instructions

Comment: You're right; Pure Emulation is related to instruction emulation. I misread the question at first.